# Email template building HTML_FONT_TINY

Tags: html, html-email

I have a basic HTML template i built. I checked it's rating using spamassin and it was given a poor score due to `HTML_FONT_TINY`. I can not find any information ragerding what this means and how my code could be in violation. Could anyone explain why HTML code could rate poorly in this instance?

This link that is provided by spamassasin is of no help
http://www.antivirushelptool.com/spamassassin/body/HTML_FONT_TINY

Answer (score 1):

It means the font size of your email is small.  If you increase the font size via HTML attribute or via CSS, this should help.  It usually is recommended to have your fonts at 13px or above. I would not go below 10px as a minimum if required for disclaimers, etc.

Good reference: http://mailchimp.blogs.com/blog/2007/06/tiny_fonts_trig.html